# Interpolate variable inside session variable name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

I'm trying to do this in my controller since I have multiple posts on a page and I want to save votes in cookies so users can only vote once. I have tried `session[:upvote][:"post_#{post.id}"] = true`

What is the recommended way of doing this? Interpolating like above doesn't work...

(I see a couple of solutions in PHP for this with concatenation, but can't seem to get above or this `session[:upvote][:"post_"+post.id] = true` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try `session[:upvote]["post_#{post.id}".to_sym]`, it should interpolate the string and then convert it into a symbol. And, *I think* you do not need the `.to_sym` part, it should work perfectly well with strings as keys in the hash.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I ended up having an array in one session key rather than having multiple session keys. `session[:upvote] = [post.id, post.id, post.id]`

Comment: You might try to check if the session is set up at some point in a `before_filter` with this code: `session[:upvotes] ||= {}`. Then, setting `session[:upvotes]["post_#{post.id}"] = true` should definitely work.